# Problem Migrating ZF2 to ZF3: Unable to resolve service "ModuleManager"

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have to migrate a project (that I did not set up back then) from Zend Framework 2 to Zend Framework 3 and I am bumping into some issues: 
the ServiceManager was extended to do some custom stuff, and here in the function `__construct()` it breaks:

```
//Zend/Mvc/Application
$this->setFactory('MvcApplication', function ($serviceManager)
{
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
    return $serviceManager->get('Application')->bootstrap();                
});
```

**"PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Unable to resolve service "ModuleManager" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?"**

I do not have added the autoload to the composer.json and I did not change to the PSR-4 standard as I read this is recommended, but not necessary. 
I have the module manager in the composer.json:

```
"zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "3.3.0",
"zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "2.8.0",
```

The ServiceManager is set up like this:

```
//Add MVC configuration
$mvcServiceManager = new \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager(isset($configuration['mvc']['service_manager']) ? $configuration['mvc']['service_manager'] : array());
$mvcServiceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $configuration['mvc']);
$mvcServiceManager->setService('ParentServiceManager', $this);
```

the `$configuration['mvc']`is an array that looks like this:

```
$configuration['mvc']['module_listener_options']['module_paths'][] = $configuration['path']['modules'];
$configuration['mvc']['modules'][] = 'AppName\Module\Error';
$configuration['mvc']['modules'][] = 'AppName\Module\Auth';
$configuration['mvc']['modules'][] = 'AppName\Module\CMS';
...etc
```

while in the file autoload.php I have:

```
//Add composer classes
include_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');

//Autoload non composer classes
Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(
    array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                'AppName' => __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'AppName'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Can anyone push me in the right direction? Do I have to switch to psr-4 with autoload in composer.json? Or is this another problem?

Thank you so much for any help! I'm quite new to the ZF and this goes a bit over my head...:-)

Cheers,
Caroline

Comment: I have multiple projects running with latest ZF3 dependencies. In `Application.php` (`\Zend\Mvc\Application`), in the `init()` function there's: `$serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();`. This is in Zend itself, meaning the alias `ModuleManager` is registered. If this does not work for you, chances are it's overwritten in your project somewhere. Please make sure that it is not. Also, could you try to remove version dependencies, update all vendors to most recent and see if/what doesn't work? Just to get an idea. Also (continued...)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, is the default ZF ServiceManager extended with good reason? If not I would really advise against changing it's implementation from the default. - With regard to PSR-4, yes, def recommended! Have a look in the [Zend Skeleton Application](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) for the syntax for the configuration.

Comment: Did you run `composer install` or `composer update`?

Comment: Hello @LeoGalleguillos, I removed the composer.lock file and did a compose install.

Comment: Hi @rkeet, thanks for the advice, I will look into that, but I think the ServiceManager implementation was changed with good reason :-/